# How can deduct results from a binary data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, categories, dummy-variable

I have four categories of products :

- Category A:
  {X800818, 
  X822707 ,
  X822708 ,
  X870082 ,
  X800810 ,
  X800323 ,
  X800835 ,
  X893890 ,
  X822541, 
  X800831}
- Category B: 
  {X830742 ,
  X841223 ,
  X841449 ,
  X870138 ,
  X810352 ,
  X870146 ,
  X800850, 
  X841236 ,
  X811712 ,
  X893314}
- Category C:
  {X893609 ,
  X890188 ,
  X893313, 
  X841271,
  X891250 ,
  X811820 ,
  X728538 ,
  X727220 ,
  X960804,
  X728904}
- Category D:
  {X727345,
  X800875 ,
  X727302 ,
  X870426 ,
  X729002 ,
  X727300 ,
  X759042 ,
  X728495 ,
  X897198, 
  X790190}

And I have a binary dataframe such that each row contains one or a bunch of products belonging to the different categories: Here is an example:

```
    X800818 X822707 X822708 X870082 X800810 X800323 X800835 X893890 X822541 X800831 X830742 X841223 X841449 

1          0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       1       0       0

2          1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0

3          1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0

4          0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1
```

I want to get this results :

1. 2 A , 1 B
2. 1 A , 1 B
3. 1 A
4. 1 B

How can i make R deduct this result from the binary dataframe ?Any suggestions ?

Comment: Give us a reproducible example. Use `dput` to post your category vectors and your matrix.

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse); df1 %>% rownames_to_column('rn') %>% gather(key, val, -rn) %>% filter(val ==1) %>% left_join(keyvaldata) %>% count(rn, grp) %>% group_by(rn) %>% summarise(new = toString(paste(n, grp)))`

Comment: In the second row, it should be `1 A, 1 B`.  The `keyvaldata` in the above code is `keyvaldata <- data.frame(key = c('X800818', 'X822707' , 'X822708' , 'X870082' , 'X800810' , ...., 'X790190'),
                   grp = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make some reproductible code, but my solution is not as clean as possible :

```
#Data Creation

A <- c("X800818","X822707","X822708","X870082","X800810","X800323","X800835","X893890","X822541","X800831")
B <- c("X830742","X841223","X841449","X870138","X810352","X870146","X800850","X841236","X811712","X893314")
C <- c("X893609","X890188","X893313","X841271","X891250","X811820","X728538","X727220","X960804","X728904")
D <- c("X727345","X800875","X727302","X870426","X729002","X727300","X759042","X728495","X897198","X790190")
df <-data.frame(c(1,0,0,1),c(0,0,0,0),c(1,1,1,1),c(1,0,1,1),c(1,0,0,1),c(0,1,0,0),c(1,0,1,1))
names(df) <- c("X800818","X800323","X841223","X811820","X960804","X727300","X728495")

#Transforming binaries to letters

for( col in names(df)) {
 for(L in LETTERS[1:4]) {
  if(col %in% get(L)) df[df[,col] == 1,col] <- L
 }
}

#Transpose 

tdf <- data.frame(t(df))

#Get Results df
res <- NULL
for (col in names(tdf)) {
levels(tdf[,col]) <- c("0",LETTERS[1:4])
res <- rbind(res,table(tdf[,col]))
}


     0 A B C D
[1,] 2 1 1 2 1
[2,] 5 1 1 0 0
[3,] 4 1 1 1 0
[4,] 2 1 1 2 1
```

Hope that will helps

Comment: Thank you , but based on the example you took , only the first and the last rows of res are correct .